# Is virtual address process-specific?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

I've been studying memory management related topics. I'm wondering, whether I've understood it correctly:

- pointer(virtual) address is process specific
- different processes can have pointers with same addresses, but these pointers get translated to different physical addresses

Am I correct about these statements? If yes, do they apply for architectures x86, x86-64 and ARMv7, ARMv8?

Comment: Did you read relevant wikipages on [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) .... ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Well, not all of them. However, I'm not sure about whether I understood it correctly. Look at answers, both of them are saying opposite thing. And if someone answers question, then he/she claims he/she knows the topic. So we've got two truths now :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well except for:

> different processes can have pointers with same addresses, but these pointers get translated to different physical addresses

while this is the general case, of course different processes *could* share mapped pages (look into shared memory) and then the pointers *could* point to the same data, given the pages are mapped to the same locations in virtual address space.

But yes, that's the correct understanding.

Comment: Also, shared memory could get mapped to different addresses in different processes.

Comment: Sure, could, but doesn't have to. Mappings of shared libraries for example ... I'll improve the wording.

Comment: Thanks. So, little fix of statement would be: **may** get translated :)

Comment: Still part of question left unanswered. Does it apply for each listed architecture?

Comment: @Miro they all have virtual memory management, so it's basically the same, yes. Implementation might differ, for example the depth of nested page tables ...